# How to add content to Tab in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have tabSheet with tabs.

```
 TabSheet tabsheet = new TabSheet();
 tabsheet.setSizeUndefined();
 tabsheet.addTab(new Label("Contents of the first tab"),"Слои");
 tabsheet.addTab(table, "Tab");
 tabsheet.addTab(new Label("Contents of the third tab"),"Межевые планы");
```

Now i want to add another component to second tab for example a horisontalLayout

```
  HorizontalLayout lo = new HorizontalLayout();
  Button newContact = new Button();
  Button search = new Button();
  Button share = new Button();
  Button help = new Button();
   lo.addComponent(newContact);
   lo.addComponent(search);
   lo.addComponent(share);
   lo.addComponent(help);
```

But how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepare a layout:

```
    VerticalLayout l1 = new VerticalLayout();
    l1.setMargin(true);
    l1.addComponent(new Label("I am a label."));
    ... add your other components here.
```

Then add it to your tabsheet:

```
    TabSheet t = new TabSheet();
    t.setHeight("200px");
    t.setWidth("400px");
    t.addTab(l1, "My Tab", icon1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should define layout of the whole tab, after that you can add to this layout another components. See example below:

```
VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
verticalLayout.setSizeFull();
tabsheet.addTab(verticalLayout, "Vertical Layout with inline components");
verticalLayout.addComponent(new Lable("Example"));
verticalLayout.addComponent(new Button("Button"));
```